# Python appends wrong parrameters into list

Tags: python, list, append

I have a problem in Python.
I created a method that adds value to empty list from two dimensional list which is created from data which are from .txt .
When i choose to append a number 4 and 2  ( from 4 ) in an empty list it shows that I added only 1 , 2 not 4 and 2 . Where is the problem?

Here is the code ( sorry , for "unknown" language in code, I'm Lithuanian , so program has to be written in this language ) 
self.PriskirtiDydžiai is the empty list where values are appended. GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS[0] is the first element of two dimensional list from where data is chosen. Its a cutout from my work. It's one of the classes method.

```
   #self.GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS  This list gets data from .txt   The list looks like that : [1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
     def GalimuDydziuPriskyrimas (self,Krovinys):                              
           DYDNR=int(input("write value (from 1 to 4): "))
           if DYDNR>len(self.GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS[0]):
                print("this number do not exist , try again")
                DYDNR=int(input("write value (from 1 to 4): "))
                self.PriskirtiDydziai.append(self.GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS[0][DYDNR-1])
           else:
                self.PriskirtiDydziai.append(self.GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS[0][DYDNR-1])
```

When I print list called GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS I get this :

```
    >>>b1.GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS
    [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Simply debug your code, you did not provide all required information. If you really think, we shall help you, provide shortest working example, showing your problem.

Comment: Lacking the ability to read Lithuanian! I suggest printing out the GalimiPriimtiDUOMENYS to see where the values are indexed. It seems like you are just getting the index wrong of where you think the elements are in the list

Answer (score 0):

Your 2d array looks like `l=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]`:

```
In [5]: l=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

In [13]: l[0][1] # index of 2
Out[13]: 2

In [14]: l[0][3] # index of four
Out[14]: 4
```

You are appending `[0][DYDNR-1]` which would need the input to be 2 to get 2 i.e `[0][2-1]`  and 4 to get 4 i.e `l[0][4-1]`.

Without running your function it is hard to see where else it could be wrong.